# Determine if determinant is exactly zero

Tags: python, math, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a lot of 10 by 10 (0,1)-matrices and I would like to determine which have determinant exactly 0 (that is which are singular). Using `scipy.linalg.det` I get a floating point number which I have to test to see if it is close to zero. Is it possible to do the calculation exactly so I can be sure I am not finding false positives?

On the other hand, maybe there is some guarantee about the smallest eigenvalue which can be used to make sure the floating point method never makes a false positive?

Comment: By a (0,1)-matrix, do you mean a binary matrix (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix) or a matrix whose values are real numbers between 0 and 1?

Comment: Good question, I didn't notice that (0, 1) part

Comment: The values are either 0 or 1 but I am working over the reals.

Comment: If it's a binary nxn matrix then the determinant is integral, and the maximum absolute value of the determinant for 10x10 is pretty small (320, I think.)  In practice you're probably safe.  Both Sage and sympy will get the integral answer natively, but I'm not sure if there's a way short of implementing your own pivot in numpy which will guarantee it.

Comment: Nice, DSM.  You should add that as an answer.

Comment: @DSM Err.. is the smallest non-zero determinant actually 1 in this case?

Comment: you can have negative determinants, but you wont get any "near" zero

Comment: @wim Good point. I mean smallest absolute value.

Comment: run `np.linalg.det((np.random.rand(10,10) < 0.5).astype(int))` a few thousand times to convince yourself  ;)

Comment: @wim I did and I don't see any determinants with absolute value less than 1 except for zero.

Comment: @Anush: as I said, the determinant is an integer, and 0 is the only integer with absolute value smaller than 1.  What I said is that the maximum absolute value of the determinant is small, which suggests that no intermediate calculation is going to introduce enough error to invalidate the result.  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @DSM I am just trying to work out if I can guarantee that I will never report a matrix as singular when it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the entries in the matrices are either 1 or 0 the smallest non-zero absolute value of a determinant is 1.  So there is no need to fear a true non-zero value that is very close to 0.

Alternatively one can apparently use sympy to get an exact answer.

Comment: @AndreasH. Determinants are sums/differences/products of their entries.  If you start with integers, you will end with an integer.

Comment: +1 Ah, I overlooked that you were talking about determinant not eigenvalues. I get your point now.

Comment: I think this is best answer. In fact you could do abs(det(M)) < 0.5 to test for singularity!

Answer (score 4):

As long as you are using floats, you can not guarantee you will get exactly zero.  I would use this:

```
scipy.allclose(det, 0)
```

You can control the tolerance with the kwargs.

---

In your case (10x10 matrices with 0,1 elements) you shouldn't have to worry about false positives.

I don't have a proof for this, but it's just geometrical intuition: the group of 10-vectors with 0/1 elements can not be "nearly" linearly dependent in the way that would be necessary for you to get a false positive using floats.  As vectors their "directions"<sup>†</sup> are necessarily discrete/atomic if elements are in 0,1.

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Think of the 3D case and generalise your thoughts to 10-dimensional space ;)</sub>

Comment: I am using np.isclose. My fear is that this might give false positives if there is a true very small eigenvalue.

Comment: They are the same function (scipy uses the one from numpy)

Comment: No point in fearing false positives. Floating point arithmetic always has errors and error tolerances

Answer (score 3):

You can use Gaussian elimination to bring the matrix to a triangular form. 
Since your elements are all 0 or 1, the calculation even using floating point arithmetic will be exact (you are only multiplying/dividing/adding/subtracting by -1, 0 and 1, which is exact).

The determinant is then 0 if one element of the diagonal is zero and nonzero otherwise.

So for this specific algorithm (Gaussian elimination), calculation of the determinant will be exact even in floating point arithmetic.

This algorithm also should be pretty efficient. It can even be implemented using integers, which is faster and shows even in a more obvious way that the problem is exactly solvable.

EDIT: the point is, that an algorithm which operates on the 0,1 matrix can be exact. It depends on the algorithm. I would check how det() is implemented and maybe, there is no issue with numerical noise, and, in fact, you could just test for det(M) == 0.0 and get neither false negatives nor false positives.

Comment: Good idea, but does scipy have row reduction?  If it does I didn't know about it ..

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: thanks, Of course I meant triangular. I corrected that.

Comment: @wim: Well you always can program it. But, I would look into the docs how det() is implemented, maybe it is already what one needs.

Comment: @Ophion Even if that is the case, you can restrict your pivot search to matrices that have a small numerical determinant from the original method. This way you'll be operating on a much smaller subset.

Comment: I'm not convinced that Gaussian elimination is necessarily exact.  I think OP doesn't need to worry about inexactness because the matrices are small, but if they were to get very large, I could see roundoff creeping in.

Comment: @AndreasH. Checking det(M) == 0 definitely doesn't work. You get plenty of determinants like 1.66533453694e-16 .

Comment: @Anush: too bad. Then the specific algorithm is not suitable. My point was, that an algorithm *can* be made exact (or even implemented in integer arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider examining the condition number rather than the determinant. In python you'd want

```
numpy.linalg.cond(x, p=None)
```

Reference http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cond.html.

That was the advice from the applied maths prof on the [coursera course on scientific computing](https://www.coursera.org/course/scientificcomp). Essentially the condition number will give you the best indication of numerical instability for operations like inverting a matrix etc, which is probably what you're interested in. See [this answer on scicomp stackexchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1330) for full details.

Answer (score 0):

how about test batches while playing with the tolerance arg, then decide on the max acceptable tolerance, rinse and repeat:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html